# Deleted user's name still shows up in "deleted by" message

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Answer https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/7314/1771 was written and deleted by the same user. The "answered by" stamp now says "user *usernumber*", but "deleted by *user **name***> Jul 17 at 16:43" persists. Is this by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, we store names directly in some cases; particularly around history.

It's really posts that get special cased really, we used to do the same thing there but we changed it so people could remove their names from posts when they delete their accounts.